# replacing a child node value PHP-XML-DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

please help me in understanding the problem with replacing the child node

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('cheat.xml');
$team1sabbr = $dom->getElementsByTagName('team1sabbr');
$textNode = $dom->createTextNode('value-1');
$textNode = $dom->importNode($textNode, true);
$team1sabbr->replaceChild($textNode, $oldNode);
$dom->save('cheat.xml');
```

its throwing an error like

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::replaceChild()
```

`cheat.xml` looks like

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<matches>

            <match id="2204">

    <Game></Game> 

        <team1sabbr></team1sabbr> 

        <team2sabbr></team2sabbr>
```

Comment: What is `$oldNode`? Where was it defined?

Comment: @Martin oh...I just copied the code from somewhere and using it, could you please show how to define it. thanks.

Comment: in which cases i may get this error and what can the reason behind that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify your code to look like the following:

```
$team1sabbr = $dom->getElementsByTagName('team1sabbr');
$textNode = $dom->createTextNode('value-1');

foreach ($team1sabbr as $team) {
    $team->parentNode->replaceChild($textNode, $team);
}
```

1. Iterate through each found element
2. Locate the parent of that element
3. Use `replaceChild` on the parent node.

**Edit::**
Through comments it seems the question was unclear.

The following is what was required.

```
$team1sabbr = $dom->getElementsByTagName('team1sabbr');

foreach ($team1sabbr as $team) {
    $team->nodeValue = 'value-1';
}
```

Comment: that works but a small problem it is coming like `<match>
    value-1
    <team2sabbr/>` instead of `<match>
   <team1sabbr> value-1
    </team1sabbr>` that is without tags its printing just child value

Comment: @BVKrishna: Thats because you're using `createTextNode`, not sure what you expected. Use `createElement` instead if you want tags. Is the question that you simply want to replace the value **inside** teamsabbr1? Ore replace the whole element with <value-1 />

Comment: I just have made changes to your quoted code as `createElement` and what i got is `<value-1/>` instead of `<team1sabbr> value-1 </team1sabbr>`

Comment: `<team1sabbr> this has to be replaced </team1sabbr>` and i want it to be like `<team1sabbr> value-1 </team1sabbr>`

Answer (score 2):

`$team1sabbr` is a `DOMNodeList`, i.e. a list of `Node`s, not a single `Node`. You need to pick one of them.

Comment: thanks. could you pls write down the way of doing it. I've placed the format of how `cheat.xml` looks like.

Comment: @BVKrishna: if you are sure there will only ever be one instance of `<team1sabbr>`, you can just do `$team1sabbr[0]->...`.

Comment: ya `team1sabbr` is of just one instance but i've some other which has two instances

Comment: @BVKrishna: if there are multiple instances and you want to replace all of them, loop through the array with a [`foreach` structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to execute the replace function for every instance.